# Is it possible to run two websites in parallel on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are planning to redesign a current ASP.NET website but would like to measure the effectiveness of the new design. We want to create two website instances and send a small proportion of traffic to the new site, ramping the traffic up only when we're confident that the new site is performing well.

Is it possible to do so with only one server (vanilla Windows Web Server 2008 without VMs) and no external load balancer? Is there a load balancer built into IIS that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are you asking if you can run two websites in IIS or if there is a built in load balancer ?

Comment: That is off topic for SO.

Comment: @Robotsushi If there is a built-in load balancer. I need to run two versions of www.example.com under the same IIS instance.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko You're probably right.

Comment: Did you already try two websites under two different port numbers under IIS?

Comment: @developer747 No, but how would that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using: Application Request Routing on IIS this is possible.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

As to whether this is on your install you may have to check, some 'Vanilla' installs include this nowadays, if  yours doesn't you can do a quick install using WebInstaller.